# AngularJS 1.x caching compiled link functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Concerning directives in AngularJS 1.x I was wondering if anyone saw any issues with caching link functions that are returned from the $compile service. For example...

```
myDirectiveModule.directive('myDirective',...
    return {
        ....
    compile:function(tElement) {
        return function($scope, $element, $attr) {
            var templateUrl='/path/to/myDirective.tpl.html';
            //link function cache would store link functions keyed on templateUrl
            //for example: cache[templateUrl] = $compile(html);
            $linkFunctionCache({
                 templateUrl:templateUrl
            }).then(function(linkFunction) {
                linkFunction($scope,function(clonedElement) {
                    $element.append(clonedElement);
                })
            });
        }

    }
....
```

I could see performance improvements on quite granular directives that may need to be compiled many times on a page

Proof of concept...
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLENVV

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. $compile(...) creates DOM tree. It can't be the same for different directive instances. (besides the fact that Angular has already been optimized for quite long time and it's a little bit naive to think that a resourceful technique could be overlooked).

Comment: $compile actually creates a linking function which you can then use to bind to your scope to ultimately create a DOM element to attach (bound to your scope).  The idea would be to reuse the linking function rather than create a branch new link function per render.

Comment: Where did you get that from and why you're asking this question if you already know the answer? I'm not sure if you understand correctly what linking function really is. But it certainly doesn't work as you expect. Try it in real-world app and you will see.

Comment: `var link = $compile('<directive>'); var el1 = link(scope1); var el2 = link(scope2)` should result in **same** element (`el1[0] === el2[0]`) that was linked once to one scope and then was re-linked to another scope. This will just screw the things up. There's nothing to cache.

Comment: Sorry for the crudeness of this example, but here is a quick proof of concept...  I think the key here is using the cloned element provided by the link function

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLENVV

Comment: Yes, it works with cloned object. However, it is not the same thing as calling $compile multiple times. Directive lifecycle becomes disrupted this way. For starters, element1 and element2 will have common controller instance. I guess you can do that for some custom heavily repeated directive if you will find out that this method truly outperforms normal compilation, and it has no side effects on this directive. But doing that for any arbitrary directive or nested ones makes no sense.

Comment: Updated the example to show element 1 and 2 have separate controller instances.  I do have a local test showing marked improvement for a commonly used directive (maybe a hundred times on a page).  Either way the purpose of this question is to answer, as you say, 'it [caching the compile method] is not the same thing as calling $compile multiple times" if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that linking function was assigned as `link = $compile('<directive>')` calling it multiple times is not the same thing as calling `$compile` multiple times. Directive lifecycle becomes disrupted this way.

All that `link` linking function does is binding compiled directive to provided scope. With help from [`cloneAttachFn`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage) parameter it is possible to create a clone of DOM tree, but that's all.

In the example above `controllerA == controllerB` check is wrong. `controllerB` is undefined there, because controller constructor runs only once. `element1.controller() === element2.controller()`.

It is possible to optimize the performance of a single directive this way if it its lifecycle suits the case (considering that performance is really being improved; this should additionally be tested with benchmarks). But a cleaner performant approach would be to just construct directive template in post-link function with jQuery or vanilla JS.

Due to the fact that this method prevents normal directive lifecycle, it is not compatible with arbitrary directive (not including possible problems with memory leaks).

Comment: Good call on controllerB being undefined. I think that fact that the directive controller would be re-used is enough for me to conclude this is a dangerous thing to do.

Comment: Yep. Not just controller constructor, but other directive functions will be executed once as well. This will be a show-stopper for most directives.